# Why OracleDataAdapter is diconnected in C#?

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms

I have created data upload application to Oracle Server using winForm and cs

But Something incomprehensible happened.

After every about 30 minutes , the application show me 'ORA-03135' error message

So, i add code to check connection state and reopen when connection is not open

However 'ORA-03135' error occurred in OracleDataAdapter , not in connection state

I don't understand this error

my code below

Winform :

```
    private void comStart()
    {

        try { 
        sp = new SerialPort();
      
        
        sp.PortName = Properties.Settings.Default.comport;
        sp.BaudRate = Properties.Settings.Default.baud;
        sp.DataBits = Properties.Settings.Default.databits;
        sp.Parity = Parity.None;
        sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    
         sp.DataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dynamoData = dynamoData + sp.ReadExisting();

                    if (dynamoData.IndexOf(etx) != -1 && dynamoData.IndexOf(stx) != -1)

             {
                 dynamoData = dynamoData.Substring(dynamoData.IndexOf(stx.ToString()) + 1, (dynamoData.IndexOf(etx.ToString()) - (dynamoData.IndexOf(stx.ToString()) + 1) ));
                 checkData(dynamoData);
             
                 dynamoData = null;
             }
            
       

        };

        sp.Open();
            label79.BackColor = Color.Lime;
        }
        catch (Exception ec)
        {
            label79.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }

    }

    private void checkData(string data)
    {
        sharedDb._db.checkConnection(); //Connection check

        string res_data = null;
        string snNo = null , rname = null , date = null;
        res_data = data;
       string[] each_data = res_data.Split(';');

       this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { 

        label13.Text = date = each_data[1]; 
        label18.Text = each_data[2]; 
        rname = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        label20.Text = snNo = dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value + "R" + each_data[0]; 
        label21.Text = each_data[3]; 
        label84.Text = each_data[4].Split('_')[0]; 

        OK_NG(label62 , each_data[4].Split('_')[1]); 

        
        label6.Text = each_data[5].Split('_')[0]; 
        OK_NG(label10, each_data[5].Split('_')[1]); 


        }));

       
        if (each_data[5].Split('_')[1].Equals("OK") && each_data[3].Equals(dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString()))
        {
            int res = sharedDb._db.insertData(res_data , rname , snNo , "0123456789"); //insert comport string Data

            if (res == 1) //insert result..
            {
               

                insertHistory(snNo , date ); //add history Data

                setlabelData( Convert.ToDateTime(date).ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") , snNo);

               label75.Text = each_data[0].Split('A')[1].ToString();


            }

        }else
        {
            
            OK_NG(label64, "NG"); 
        }


   }
```

CS (sharedDb):

```
public static class sharedDb
    {
        public static db _db = null;

        public static void initDB()
        {
            _db = new db();
        }
    }
```

CS (db) :

```
 class db(){
 public  void connectdb()
        {


            connected = true;
            orc = new OracleConnection(connect_url);
            orc.Open();
            setDbAdapter();


        }
  public void checkConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (orc.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                   
                    orc.Open();
                    setDbAdapter();
                }
            }
            catch (OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("checkConntion Error Message :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void setDbAdapter()
        {
            oda = new OracleDataAdapter();
           
            oda.SelectCommand = orc.CreateCommand(); 
            oda.InsertCommand = orc.CreateCommand(); 
            oda.UpdateCommand = orc.CreateCommand(); 
            oda.DeleteCommand = orc.CreateCommand(); 
          
        }
  public int insertData(string data , string rname , string snNo , string cname)
        {
            int res = 0;
            checkConnection();

            try
            {
              
                string insertQuery = null;
                string[] each_data = null;

                each_data = data.Split(';');

                

                insertQuery = "insert into FE_DATA values ( null , null , null , null , '" + rname + "','" + cname + "', '" + each_data[1] + "','" + each_data[2] + "', '" + snNo + "','','" + each_data[3] + "',";

                for (int i = 4; i < each_data.Length - 2; i++)
                {
                    insertQuery += "'" + each_data[i].Split('_')[0] + "','" + each_data[i].Split('_')[1] + "',";
                }

                insertQuery = insertQuery + "'" + each_data[17].Split('_')[1] + "')";
               

                 oda.InsertCommand.CommandText = insertQuery;
                 res = oda.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (OracleException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message); //'ORA-03135' Error
            }
            
            return res;
        }
       
}
```

Comment: I think my first port of call would be to look at why I had a connection open for 35 minutes!

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using ? there are reported bugs for this error

Comment: Oracle version is 11g .. is what bug??  connection time is not matter for me because i check connection state and reopen when connection is closed

Answer (score 0):

The oracle error ORA-03135 often occurs when a firewall terminates the connection.

This website gives some advice on how you can try to mitigate this:
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_03135_connection_lost_contact.htm

In the past we had problems with long-running queries being timed-out by the network, and our network admin had to make exceptions for us.

Comment: of course firewall port is open '1521' on client pc and server too. But Server and client PC ip bands are different. is this the problem?? what should i check ??

Comment: The port is obviously open, otherwise you cannot connect at all.  But a firewall somewhere is disconnecting you after 30 mins.  It could be on your client-PC, server, or somewhere in the network.  So you need to check this and talk to your network-admin and see if the advise in the article helps.